# Dynamic percentage in number range

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, math

I have a range of prices for multiple products from 1$ to 100$. As well, as I have understanging that for product with cost of **1$** is **15%** of margin will apply and for **100$** product - **5%.**

Mean that:
*1.* 1$ product will cost 1 + 1 * 0.15 = 1.15$
*2.* 100$ product will cost 100 + 100 * 0.05 = 105$

Question is how to calculate margin percentage for all range of numbers between 1$ and 100$?

I have tried to different approaches but in the end I just don't understand how to make this calculation dynamic, so I will apply formula to a big data range and get the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate with delta and add the starting value of percent.

Basically you calculate the [slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) and multiply it with a value to get a result. You need to add the offset as well. Here you have a decreasing (function) line.

```js
const
    fn = (price0, price1, percent0, percent1) => price =>
         (percent0 - percent1) * (price - price0) / (price1 - price0) + percent1;

console.log(...[1, 50.5, 100].map(fn(1, 100, 15, 5)));
```

Comment: Appretiate and thank you very much, I breefly tried it in codepen and works as charm. Can you share how this approach called in Math or JS, I just courious to learn a bit more theory behind this algorithm to understand it deeply

Comment: please have a look to the link above.